# How bad is to use reflection in a ModelValidationProvider?

Tags: c#, reflection, asp.net-mvc-3, data-annotations

I'm currently trying to find a way to simplify using ErrorMessage from DataAnnotations. After reading on the subject the most common sollution (to create a class based on each Attribute and automatically define the ErrorMessageResourceName and ErrorMessageResourceType) doesn't please me. So I decided to override the ModelValidationProvider to do so.

Unfortunatelly I had to resort to Reflection in my solution and I'm well aware of the performance cost from this technique. I'm already considering "caching" the property info for each modelValidator so that I don't have to run the GetProperties everytime. Any other suggestion/criticism for using this approach?

```
public class LocalizedDataAnnotationsModelValidatorProvider : DataAnnotationsModelValidatorProvider
{
    protected override IEnumerable<ModelValidator> GetValidators(ModelMetadata metadata, ControllerContext context, IEnumerable<Attribute> attributes)
    {
        var baseReturn = base.GetValidators(metadata, context, attributes);
        var resourceManager = Validation.ResourceManager;
        var culture = Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture;

        foreach (var modelValidator in baseReturn)
        {
            var type = modelValidator.GetType();
            var attributeProp = type.GetProperties(BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance).FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name == "Attribute");

            var attribute = attributeProp.GetValue(modelValidator, null) as ValidationAttribute;

            if (attribute != null)
            {
                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(attribute.ErrorMessage))
                {
                    var attributeName = attribute.GetType().Name.Replace("Attribute", string.Empty);
                    attribute.ErrorMessage = resourceManager.GetString(attributeName, culture);
                }
            }
        }

        return baseReturn;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## It's bad, because it is unnecessary.

I don't see what you are gaining from reflection when you can just do:

<s>foreach (var modelValidator in baseReturn)
        {
            if(modelValidator is DataAnnotationsModelValidator){
                 var attribute = ((DataAnnotationsModelValidator)modelValidator).Attribute;
                 if(attribute != null && string.IsNullOrEmpty(attribute.ErrorMessage)){
                        var attributeName = attribute.GetType().Name.Replace("Attribute", string.Empty);
                        attribute.ErrorMessage = resourceManager.GetString(attributeName, culture);
                    }
                 }
            } 
        }</s>

Update, that doesn't work because the `Attribute` property is `protected internal`.  But, you could still do:

```
  foreach(var validationAttribute in attributes.OfType<ValidationAttribute>()){
            var attributeName = attribute.GetType().Name.Replace("Attribute", string.Empty);
            attribute.ErrorMessage = resourceManager.GetString(attributeName, culture);
  }
```

Comment: You cant access Attribute. It's flaged as internal protected.

Comment: Hey, it worked... thanks. At least I got to learn about Reflection.Emit and HyperDescriptor in the process.

Answer (score 2):

Well, caching properties info is one way, but i would suggest you to look into Reflection.Emit.

Here is good example how to accelerate dynamic property access (instead of standard reflection GetValue): [HyperDescriptor: Accelerated dynamic property access](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/HyperPropertyDescriptor.aspx)

By using Reflection.Emit you will get much better performances.

Answer (score 1):

Its not bad at all.  Don't worry about it.

Using a similar technique I rarely got above 60ms of overhead from reflection.  Don't prematurely optimize.

Once this app goes into production you're almost guaranteed to get more bang from the buck optimizing stored procedures and media file sizes to improve load times.

Comment: Iterate 60ms ten times and now you over half a second. I would highlight this risk in your answer.

Comment: @Slappy and if you go 10000000000 times? Whats your point?  This executes once during ModelBinding.  I'll add when I got 60 ms the form had about 60 fields across a couple of nested objects.

Comment: The question clearly states "Any other suggestion/criticism for using this approach?" My point is your answer is misleading since you throw out 60ms like its a fixed cost. I simply said to point out that this cost is not constant and can vary. I optimized a site just the other day that incurred a massive performance penalty because of doing reflection to build up an EDMX connection string. This "cost" was only 25ms, however when called multiple times made a huge impact.

Comment: So far in my testing it's ok... I added a simple caching for most of the validators and let's see how this goes. If it gets to be a performance bottleneck i'll try Reflection.Emit as suggested.

Answer (score 0):

Your best/easiest option here is iterate through the assembly on application start and cache what you can.